# Combine multiple ggplot animation together?

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I have two ggplot animations from two different datasets, one is animation for geom_path, the other is for geom_points. I want to combine them together with the same time state, and the expected result looks like [Make multiple geoms animated in ggplot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56510139/make-multiple-geoms-animated-in-ggplot).

[image]
[image]

Here is my R code

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)
xx=c(1,1)
vv=c(-1,0)
ep=0.2
L=5
dl=10
s=15
#generate data
data<-matrix(0,L*dl,2)
data_all<-matrix(0,L*dl*s,2)
for(i in 1:L){
  for(j in 1:(s*dl)){
    data_all[(i-1)*s*dl+j,]=cos(2*ep*(j-1))*xx+sin(2*ep*(j-1))*vv
  }
  for(j in 1:dl){
    data[(i-1)*dl+j,]=cos(ep*(j-1))*xx+sin(ep*(j-1))*vv
    if(j==dl){
      xx=data[i*dl,]
      vv=rnorm(2)*4
    }
  }
}
t<-rep(c(1:L),each=dl)
dat=cbind(t,data)
dat<-as.data.frame(dat)
colnames(dat)=c("t","x1","x2")
p1=ggplot(dat,aes(x = x1, 
                 y = x2)) +
  geom_path()+
  transition_reveal(t)
p1  

t2<-rep(c(1:L),each=dl*s)
dat_all=cbind(t2,data_all)
dat_all<-as.data.frame(dat_all)
colnames(dat_all)=c("t","x1","x2")
pp=ggplot(dat_all,aes(x = x1, y = x2)) +
  geom_point()
p2 <- pp + 
  transition_states(t,
                    transition_length = 0.1,
                    state_length = 5)

p2
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)
xx=c(1,1)
vv=c(-1,0)
ep=0.2
L=5
dl=10
s=15
#generate data
data<-matrix(0,L*dl,2)
data_all<-matrix(0,L*dl*s,2)
for(i in 1:L){
  for(j in 1:(s*dl)){
    data_all[(i-1)*s*dl+j,]=cos(2*ep*j)*xx+sin(2*ep*j)*vv
  }
  for(j in 1:dl){
    data[(i-1)*dl+j,]=cos(ep*j)*xx+sin(ep*j)*vv
    if(j==dl){
      xx=data[i*dl,]
      vv=rnorm(2)*4
    }
  }
}

t<-rep(c(1:L),each=dl)
dat=cbind(t,data)
dat<-as.data.frame(dat)
colnames(dat)=c("t","x1","x2")


t2<-rep(c(1:L),each=dl*s)
dat_all=cbind(t2,data_all)
dat_all<-as.data.frame(dat_all)
colnames(dat_all)=c("t","x1","x2")


ggplot(dat,aes(x = x1, y = x2)) +
  geom_path()+
  geom_point(data=dat_all) +
  transition_reveal(t)
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe my description is not exact. What I expect is that in each frame, when the path is moving,  there is an ellipse was shown as a background(p2). And I already group the data contains in the same ellipse by t.